# How can I Implement a dynamic timeout in Teststack White?

Tags: ui-automation

How can I Implement a dynamic timeout in Teststack White?
Ex. I am trying to locate an element after a postback event on web-browser. So there will be a delay before the element loads or the page may timeout.
For both scenarios, a static timeout using Thread.Sleep works but how to implement a dynamic timeout interface that will continue execution if element is detected before timeout cap or will be timed-out when timeout cap is reached.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can implement extension method to get the element and put a wait condition inside.

```
public static T GetWithWait<T>(this Window window, SearchCriteria searchCriteria, int timeout = 30) where T : UIItem
{
    T result = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < timeout; i++)
    {
        result = window.Get<T>(searchCriteria);
        if (result != null)
        {
            return result;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
    return result;
}
```

From Window object you can call this method with SearchCriteria you generally use to find the element.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use timeouts locally, take a look at

```
using (CoreAppXmlConfiguration.Instance.ApplyTemporarySetting(c => c.BusyTimeOut= 1500))
{
   // your code here
}
```

Hope this helps.

Rik

Answer (score 1):

> White strives to eliminate any need whatsoever for doing Thread.Sleep and retry in your test programs. So if you find yourself doing these things in your program, please use any one applicable options below. If you don't find it, please raise an issue.

-

> There are cases where the above two strategy aren’t enough and hence white provides its own wait mechanism. In this test program waits until the certain condition matches. As soon as the condition matches it would return. There is maximum wait duration. This duration can be configured by setting BusyTimeout property.

-

> Steps to hook you custom wait:
>   Implement the interface White.Core.Configuration.IWaitHook.
>   Implement the WaitFor method in it to wait for as long as your test requires. White passed in the UIItemContainer (most of the time this is just the window) object to provide the context of call. e.g. you can wait till you can find a UI Item in this container. Set the wait hook by setting CoreAppXmlConfiguration.Instance.AdditionalWaitHook value

```
public class CustomWait : IWaitHook
{
    public CustomWait()
    {
        CoreAppXmlConfiguration.Instance.AdditionalWaitHook = this;
    }

    // Implementation of the IWaitHook interface
    public void WaitFor(UIItemContainer uiItemContainer)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

[TestStack.White - Waiting](http://teststackwhite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/AdvancedTopics/Waiting/)